# Tablet version of Ubuntu that runs on ARM A20 processor

Tags: tablet

I like to download Tablet version of Ubuntu that runs on ARM A20 processor but unable to find it. Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link with directions - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

The name of what you are wanting is called "Ubuntu Touch".